# Use of "in case of" sentence in past

Tags: expressions, prepositions

I am wondering whether "in case of" with a verb in the past tense, like "decided," creates a correct expression. 
For example:

> ...in case of he decided to reply.

Thank you

Comment: Typically, you would say: _in case he decided to reply_ (no _of_). You might also be interested in checking out [ell.se].

Comment: *In case of* is only used with nouns, like *in case of fire, pull alarm handle.* When it's used with a verb phrase, like "he decided", use *in case* like J.R. says.

Comment: I agree with @J.R. and stangdon. Meanwhile, you could also use "in case" with nouns. According to this [site](http://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/various-grammar-rules/in-case-in-case-of), the difference is whether or not you are actively preparing for the event mentioned within the "in case." For example, "Bring more bottles (active preparation), in case this bottle breaks (event)."

Comment: ...In case of his decision to reply. Would also be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **in case** with the ***Past Simple*** but you have to follow **tense agreement** rules.

- She **took** her mobile with her *in case* he **decided** to call. *(PAST PRECAUTION)*
- She **will take** her mobile with her *in case* he **decides** to call. *(PRESENT PRECAUTION)*

Notice that:

1. **In case** *(conjunction or adverb)* - *expresses that we are doing something in preparation for something which might happen; in order to be prepared for possible future situations. It is often used before before a pronoun or at the end of a sentence. We don’t use **in case** to mean **if**.*

   - Shall I keep some chicken salad for your brother in case he’s hungry when he gets here? *(conjunction)*
   - In case I forget later, here are the keys to the garage. *(conjunction)*
   - She knows she’s passed the oral exam, but she doesn’t want to say anything just in case. *(adverb)*
2. **In case of** *(preposition)* - *used to say what we should do if or when something happens. It is followed by a noun.*

   - Use this fire extinguisher in case of fire.
   - In case of an error, run this batch file.
   - In case of breakdown, please press the alarm button and call this number. *(if and when the lift breaks down)*

Sources:

1. [**In case (of) from English Grammar Today**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-and-wishes/in-case-of)
2. [**If vs. In case from Grammar-Quizzes.com**](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/9-6.html)

Answer (score 0):

When followed by an independent clause, the "of" is omitted. So your example would be:

> ...in case he decided to reply.

The "of" is necessary when the next word or phrase is a noun. (the noun can have describing adjectives)

> In case of fire...

If you wanted to use "of" in your example, you could change it to:

> ...in case of his reply.